# Conectar PHP com Oracle

Tags: php, oracle, conexão

Estou tentando conectar o PHP (WAMP) com Oracle mas recebo o seguinte erro:

> Call to undefined function ora_logon()

Código que estou utilizando:

```
$db = "(description =
(address =
 (protocol = tcp)
 (host = www.servidor.com.br) //link omitido
 (port = 1521)) (connect_data = (service_name = www.servidor.com.br) //link omitido
)
)";
// Conexão com Oracle usando OCI
$c = ora_logon('user@linkomitico.com.br', 'fabrica');
```

Comment: A extensão do oracle está habilitada?

Comment: Está habilitado:
`extension=php_oci8.dll      
extension=php_oci8_11g.dll 
extension=php_pdo_oci.dll`

Comment: Tem o link da documentação de `ora_logon` so achei algo referente ao php4. Com [oci_connect](http://php.net/manual/en/function.oci-connect.php) vc consegue fazer a conexão?

Answer (score 1):

A função `ora_logon` era uma função usada antigamente (a muito tempo mesmo) no *PHP4*, hoje não usamos mais ela, agora utilizamos `oci_login` por exemplo, que permite acesso aos 12c, 11g, 10g, 9i e 8i.

1. Edite o arquivo `php.ini` e remova o ponto e virgula da seguinte linha (se for windows)

   ```
   extension=php_oci8_11g.dll
   ```

   Se for *nix:

   ```
   extension=oci8.so
   ```

### Windows:

1. Faça download do [OTN Instant Client page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/instant-client/index-100365.html) - provavelmente o 32bit, mas se falhar e o seu php for 64bit, talvez você deva tentar ele.
2. Extraia o arquivo baixado em `C:\instantclient_11_2`
3. Adicione o caminho as *Variáveis do Sistema* (`PATH`)
   Menu Iniciar > Painel de Controle > Sistema e Segurança > Sistema > Configurações avançadas do sistema (ou digite no executar/cmd `SystemPropertiesAdvanced`)
4. Procure o botão chamado *Variáveis de Ambiente*
5. Tem duas áreas, Variáveis de usuário e *Variáveis do Sistema*, procure em *Variáveis do Sistema* a variável `PATH` e clique em editar
6. Adicione no final isto (cuidado para não apagar o que já tiver) `;C:\instantclient_11_2`

As função usada para conectar usada é `oci_login`, lista de funções da documentação http://php.net/manual/en/book.oci8.php

Exemplo de uso:

```
<?php
$conn = oci_connect('hr', 'welcome', 'localhost/XE');
if (!$conn) {
    $e = oci_error();
    trigger_error(htmlentities($e['message'], ENT_QUOTES), E_USER_ERROR);
}

$stid = oci_parse($conn, 'SELECT department_id, department_name FROM departments');
oci_execute($stid);

while (($row = oci_fetch_assoc($stid)) != false) {
    echo $row['DEPARTMENT_ID'] . " " . $row['DEPARTMENT_NAME'] . "<br>\n";
}

oci_free_statement($stid);
oci_close($conn);
```

Answer (score 0):

Se ainda não encontrou solução, veja o seguinte:
- Descomente o extension=php_oci8.dll extension=php_oci8_11g.dll extension=php_pdo_oci.dll no php.ini
- Instale o client 11g, modo administrador
- Copiar o TNS Names para a pasta C:\oracle\product\10.2.0\client_1\NETWORK\ADMIN
– Adicionar na variável de ambiente o path Client e do PHP.

Com esses passos minhas aplicações aqui funcionam normalmente.