# Extensão PDO_OCI do PECL/PHP obsoleta. Como proceder?

Tags: php, oracle, pdo, centos, extensão

Preciso instalar a extensão pdo_oci do PHP para trabalhar com banco de dados Oracle, via PDO. Porém, verifiquei que a extensão disponível via [PECL](https://pecl.php.net/package/PDO_OCI) está obsoleta e não mais será mantida.

Pelo que entendi [neste link](http://bencornwell.com/112/#comment-1991) (não sei se entendi corretamente), as versões mais recentes do PHP já vêm com o PDO_OCI.

Gostaria de saber como devo proceder, pois não encontrei nada conclusivo.
Estou utilizando o CentOS 6.6 com PHP 5.6.

OBS: Já tenho instalado os RPMs basic e devel do ORACLE Instanclient

Obrigado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obrigado @guilerme-nascimento.
Consegui instalar da seguinte forma (lembrando que uso o CentOs 6.6):

**Baixar o PHP**

> $ wget https://www.php.net/get/php-5.6.10.tar.gz/from/this/mirror

**Descompactar e mudar para a pasta descompactada**

> $ tar -xzf php-5.6.10.tar.gz
> $ cd php-5.6.10

**Executar o comando configure com os parâmetros desejados (abaixo meu exemplo)**

> ./configure
> --prefix=/usr
> --sysconfdir=/etc
> --localstatedir=/var
> --datadir=/usr/share/php
> --mandir=/usr/share/man
> --with-config-file-path=/etc
> --with-config-file-scan-dir=/etc/php.d
> --with-zlib
> --enable-bcmath
> --with-bz2
> --enable-calendar
> --with-gdbm
> --with-gmp
> --enable-ftp
> --with-gettext
> --enable-mbstring
> --with-readline
> --with-apxs2
> --with-pdo-oci=instantclient,/usr,12.1
> --enable-dba=shared
> --with-pdo-mysql --with-mysql-sock=/var/mysql/mysql.sock
> --with-pdo-pgsql

**OBS:** Durante esse passo podem ocorrer erros, devido à dependências que precisam ser instaladas antes, como o db4 e db4-devel. No meu caso, fui executando o comando, vendo qual dependência estava dando erro. Depois de identificado, instalava a dependência (sempre instalando também a versão **devel** de cada pacote) e executava novamente para ver a próxima dependência que faltava. Fiz isso até o comando rodar sem erros.

**Compilando e instalando**

> $ make && make install

Neste ponto, o PHP já está instalado.
Para se certificar, rode o seguinte comando:

> $ php -v

Mas antes de concluír, precisamos fazer alguns ajustes...

**Copiar o php.ini para o diretório correto**

> **Caso esteja em um servidor local**
> $ cp php.ini-development /etc/php.ini
> **Caso esteja em um servidor de produção**
> $ cp php.ini-production /etc/php.ini

**Abrir arquivo de configuração do apache para edição**

> $ vi /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf

**Acrescentar as linhas abaixo para o Apache interpretar o PHP**

> AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
> AddType application/x-httpd-php-source .phps

**Salve e reinicie o Apache**

> $ service httpd restart

## Pronto! Agora já deve estar tudo funcionando corretamente!

A desvantagem deste método (pelo menos até onde notei) é que, sempre que precisar algum módulo como o PDO_MYSQL, PDO_PGSQL etc, não poderá instalar via pacote, pois não irá funcionar.
Para instalar alguns, pode ser via PECL, exceto os que estão desatualizados, como o [PDO_MYSQL](https://pecl.php.net/package/PDO_MYSQL) e PDO_OCI, onde deve-se compilar o php novamente para instalar estes.

Answer (score 1):

Conforme o link o que é obsoleto é a versão PECL, a partir do PHP5.3 esta extensão é padrão no PHP e por isto talvez o repositório do PECL tenha sido descontinuado.

Se as extensões ainda não estiver no servidor, recomendo instalar usando comando:

```
yum install php-pdo
```

### Instalando OCI8 como uma extensão compilada estaticamente

Configure o PHP para include OCI8 usanado uma das linhas a seguir:

- Se você estiver usando Oracle Instant Client faça isto:

  ```
  ./configure --with-oci8=instantclient,/path/to/instant/client/lib
  ```
- Se estiver usando Oracle database or full Oracle Client:

  ```
  ./configure --with-oci8=$ORACLE_HOME
  ```

Após a configuração, siga os passos da compilação normal, ex: `make install`

### Instalando OCI8 como uma extensão "Shared"

A opção de configuração compartilhada constrói o OCI8 como uma biblioteca compartilhada que pode ser carregado dinamicamente em PHP. A construção de uma extensão compartilhada permite OCI8 para ser atualizado facilmente, sem afetar o resto do PHP.

- Se estiver usando as bibliotecas "free » Oracle Instant Client":

  ```
  ./configure --with-oci8=shared,instantclient,/path/to/instant/client/lib
  ```

  Se o Instant Client foi instalado através de arquivos ZIP, crie os links simbolicos primeiro, por exemplo: `ln -s libclntsh.so.12.1 libclntsh.so`
- Se estiver usando uma instalação baseada em RPM do Oracle Instant Client:

  ```
  ./configure --with-oci8=shared,instantclient,/usr/lib/oracle/<version>/client/lib
  ```

  Por exemplo `--with-oci8=shared,instantclient,/usr/lib/oracle/12.1/client/lib`

  Note que o suporte inicial ao Oracle Instant Client apareceu no PHP 4.3.11 e 5.0.4, originalmente usado com `--with-oci8-instant-client` para configurar o PHP.
- Se estiver usando Oracle database ou full Oracle Client installation:

  ```
  ./configure --with-oci8=shared,$ORACLE_HOME
  ```

  Verifique se o usuário do servidor web (nobody, www) tem acesso as bibliotecas, inicializando os arquivos e `tnsnames.ora` (se estiver usando) sob o diretoriio `$ORACLE_HOME`. Com Oracle 10gR2, você talvez necessite rodar o utilitário `$ORACLE_HOME/install/changePerm.sh` para dar acesso ao diretorio.

### Habilitar o php.ini

Para habilitar o "Oracle" no PHP você deve abrir o arquivo php.ini e descomentar a linha (remover o `;` do começo):

```
;extension=pdo.so
;extension=pdo_oci.so
;extension=pdo_oci8.so
```

Ficando assim:

```
extension=pdo.so
extension=pdo_oci.so
extension=pdo_oci8.so
```

e reiniciar o servidor.

Se o *OracleInstantClient* não estiver "funcionando", pode ser a versão errada para o PHP. Tente baixar deste link a versão correta para o seu servidor:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/instant-client/index-100365.html

Note que a extensão PDO para [PHP é experimental](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-oci.php):

> This extension is EXPERIMENTAL. The behaviour of this extension including the names of its functions and any other documentation surrounding this extension may change without notice in a future release of PHP. This extension should be used at your own risk.

Devido a este fato, se surgir algum problema decorrente, tente usar as funções do `oci8.so`, veja: [Conectar PHP com Oracle](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/71364/3635)

Comment: @jflizandro editei a resposta, use o comando `yum install php-pdo`

Comment: Dando uma pesquisada entendi melhor. Na verdade não só só habilitar a extensão no php.ini, pois ela não vem no PHP instalado via repositório.
Descobri que é necessário instalar o PHP através do fonte e compilar ele com o comando **./configure --with-pdo-oci=instantclient,/usr,VERSÂO_DO_INSTANTCLIENT**.
Consegui instalar tranquilo e o PDO_OCI habilitado certinho. Único problema é que as páginas php estão sendo exibidas como texto. Irei realizar alguns testes em VM, refazendo todo o processo.

Comment: O pdo já estava instalado, porém o PDO_OCI não vêm no pacote, pois para compilar ele é necessário apontar o caminho do instantclient, que pode variar.

Comment: @jflizandro Adicionei alguns detalhes na resposta da instalação, veja se ajuda