# Como instalar o oci8 no host linux do Azure DevOps

Tags: php, linux, oracle12c, microsoft-azure

Tenho uma aplicação php que necessita de uma conexão oracle 12c e ao realizar a "compilação" no azure o seguinte erro é exibido durante o `composer install`

> Problem 1
>       - Installation request for yajra/laravel-oci8 v5.5.9 -> satisfiable by yajra/laravel-oci8[v5.5.9].
>       - yajra/laravel-oci8 v5.5.9 requires ext-oci8 >=2.0.0 -> the requested PHP extension oci8 is missing from your system.

Olhando alguns sites da internet, vi que é necessário instalar o PECL e logo após instalar o oci8.

<s>Descobri alguns códigos bash que realizam a instalação do PECL e oci8, porém o mesmo necessita de um instalador de pacotes, apt, dpkg e o host linux do azure não possui instalador de pacotes para executar o arquivo bash.</s>

Informações detalhadas:

- VM: Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS
- Versão PHP: 7.2
- Azure DevOps (Nuvem)

Links relacionado ao problema:

- [oracle-instant-client (Gist GitHub)](https://gist.github.com/cbj4074/fa761f60b6f8db431539d76ebfba828e)
- [How to install PECL on a linux system (Stack Exchange)](https://serverfault.com/questions/254017/how-to-install-pecl-on-a-linux-system)
- [oic8 (pecl)](https://pecl.php.net/package/oci8)
- [Run a self-hosted agent behind a web proxy (docs.microsoft)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/proxy?view=azure-devops&tabs=windows)
- [yajra/laravel-oci8 (GitHub)](https://github.com/yajra/laravel-oci8/blob/5.5/oci8.sh)

Edit 1:

Executei este script baseado em tutorias que encontrei porem o problema ainda persiste.

```sh
sudo apt-get install php-pear;
sudo apt-get install php5-dev;
sudo apt-get install libcurl3-openssl-dev;
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart ;

sudo apt-get update -qq;
sudo apt-get -y install -qq build-essential unzip wget libaio1;
sudo mkdir -p /opt/oracle;
wget https://github.com/bumpx/oracle-instantclient/raw/master/instantclient-basic-linux.x64-12.1.0.2.0.zip;
wget https://github.com/bumpx/oracle-instantclient/raw/master/instantclient-sdk-linux.x64-12.1.0.2.0.zip;
sudo unzip -o ./instantclient-basic-linux.x64-12.1.0.2.0.zip -d /opt/oracle;
sudo unzip -o ./instantclient-sdk-linux.x64-12.1.0.2.0.zip -d /opt/oracle;
sudo ln -s /opt/oracle/instantclient/sqlplus /usr/bin/sqlplus;
sudo ln -s /opt/oracle/instantclient_12_1 /opt/oracle/instantclient;
sudo ln -s /opt/oracle/instantclient/libclntsh.so.12.1 /opt/oracle/instantclient/libclntsh.so;
sudo ln -s /opt/oracle/instantclient/libocci.so.12.1 /opt/oracle/instantclient/libocci.so;
sudo pecl channel-update pecl.php.net;
echo 'instantclient,/opt/oracle/instantclient' | sudo pecl install oci8;
```

Comment: Caro @Propeus alguma destas resolve https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/71549/3635 ?

Comment: @Guilherme Nascimento agradeço pela ajuda, porém a solução do tópico não teve efeito neste problema.

Comment: Caro Propeus, mas ate aonde conseguiu ir da solucao sugerida? Aonde falhou exatamente? Porque uma coisa é não funcionar para o seu caso, outra é você não ter compreendido bem a solução e por isso não conseguiu resolver.

Comment: Olá @Guilherme Nascimento, desculpe a demora pela resposta. Há dois pontos que impedem de seguir suas instruções, primeiro, o comando "yum install php-pdo" não funciona para o meu caso pois a vm de build é Ubuntu com o gerenciador de pacore apt-get, a solução mais próxima que encontrei para este problema foi este link [(digitalocean)](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/how-to-enable-extension-pdo-in-ubuntu-14-04), o segundo foi uma duvida sobre o comando "./configure", este comando seria executado no diretório da oic8 ou no php?

Comment: Mas é só adaptar caro Propeus, se conhece UBuntu, conhece APT, uma pesquisa rapida sobre apt-get pdo e vc saberia o comando para ubuntu e debian, feito isso você pode seguir com as demais instruções, e quando travar pesquisar sobre a parte que não é sobre ubuntu... claro que ao invés de editar o php.ini em ubuntu você pode usar o phpenmod`sudo phpenmod pdo_oci` (se for php7)... mas isso é uma de mais de uma forma de se fazer.