# Fatal error: Call to undefined function oci_connect()

Tags: php, oracle

Erro ao conectar no banco Oracle.
Segue abaixo o código em PHP:

```
<?php 
$ora_bd = "(DESCRIPTION=
      (ADDRESS_LIST=
        (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP) 
          (HOST=192.168.0.249)(PORT=1521)
        )
      )
      (CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=CSTESTE))
 )"; 

$ora_conexao = oci_connect('refeitorio', 'tiete2018', $ora_bd);

if (!$ora_conexao) { 
$erro = oci_error();
    trigger_error(htmlentities($erro['message'], ENT_QUOTES), E_USER_ERROR);
    exit;
}else{                                                         
echo "Conectado com Sucesso.";  
}
```

Lembrando que já habilitei os seguintes comandos no `php.ini`

```
extension=php_oci8.dll
extension=php_pdo_oci.dll
extension=php_oracle.dll
```

Aparece o seguinte erro:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function oci_connect() in C:\wamp64\www\Sistema\Refeicao\Core\TesteCon.php:11 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\wamp64\www\Sistema\Refeicao\Core\TesteCon.php on line 11

Comment: Esse erro acontece quando a extensão não foi instalada. Só habilitar no `php.ini` não basta. Tem algo a mais que você fez?

Comment: Já instalou o instantclient no seu sistema? https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/71364/4751

Comment: Eu já tenho o client instalado na minha máquina.
Utilizo esse client pois tenho 2 software utilizando Oracle, caminho: C:\oracle\product\10.2.0\client_1

Comment: qual a versao do seu php?

Comment: 5.6.31, mas também tentei a versão 7.0.23

Comment: @J.C.Galhardi a versão 7 é compativel somente com instant client 12, tome cuidado com isso! aconselho a conferir todos os passos que te passei e me mandar todas as versoes de tudo que voce instalou (client, php etc) e tb print das variaveis de ambiente configurada

Comment: Foi dentro da bin do apache ou dentro da pasta bin/php/ext/ ???

Comment: Consegui colocando no PATH das Variáveis de Sistema o caminho do Instant Client ("C:\instant_client") e reinicia o PC.

Comment: No meu caso precisei instalar o XAMPP na versão 32 bit. [Download da versão do XAMPP 32 Bits](https://sourceforge.net/projects/xampp/files/XAMPP%20Windows/7.3.2/)

Comment: Essa solução funciona para o Oracle 10.2.0 também, só que para isso é preciso baixar o instantclient. Utilizei o instantcliente 19.

Answer (score 1):

Tive esse problema recentemente e a solução foi esta:

Você baixa o `xamp` ou `wamp` 32 ou 64 `bits` esta terá que ser sua versão do `instant client oracle`

após instalar eles com qualquer versão do `php`, ao chamar uma função `oci_oracle` vai dar erro.

Você precisa então primeiro habilitar as extensões no **php.ini**

um exemplo de como acessar o php.ini no xamp:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

habilite essas extensões nessa ordem:

```
extension=php_oci8.dll
extension=php_oci8_12c.dll
extension=php_oracle.dll
```

Observação: se não tiver para habilitar, crie e verifique a segunda, eu coloquei 12c pois meu `instant client` é 12c.

Depois disso você precisa instalar o instant client.

Abre o `cmd` **COMO ADMINISTRADOR** vai no local do instant client e roda `odbc_install`

O próximo passo é o mais importante, e é por isso que eu tava levando uma surra:

você precisa adicionar no `PATH` onde está seu `oracle instant client`:

[image: insira o código aqui]

e criar a TNS.ADMIN:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

faz isso para as duas caixas de variáveis, sistema e usuário:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Feito isso, configure o arquivo **tnsnames.ora** reinicie sua máquina, e você poderá usar as funções `oci`.

> Seu instant client tem que estar na mesma versão do php, 32 ou 64

baixando o php 7 no php.ini dele ele pede a versão 12 do `instant client` como você pode ver na foto.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Eu tenho o client 10g. Não seria mais fácil instalar o Wamp 32bits invés de ter que instalar outro client ?

Comment: você quem sabe, é só fazer o processo para o client 10

Comment: Instalei a versão 32x, porém continua do mesmo jeito.

Comment: vou subir uma maquina virtual e fazer o processo com o client 10g, mas se vc seguiu certinho os passos teria que funcionar..

Answer (score 0):

Cara, tive esse problema e ele me tirou o sono por alguns dias. No meu caso o erro era:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function oci_connect()

Só consegui resolver reinstalando tudo na versão 32 bits. Pra mim funcionou bem. Eu instalei o XAMPP xampp-win32-7.3.2-0-VC15 e habilitei a extensão:

```
 extension=oci8_12c
```

no arquivo php.ini. Vale a pena conferir também se a extensão está no lugar certo:

```
extension_dir="C:\xampp\php\ext"
```

Depois disso você instala o Oracle Instant Client na versão certa, no meu caso foi 32-bits na versão 12_2. O próximo passo é colocar esse caminho nas variáveis de ambiente, como o amigo acima falou. 
Depois de fazer isso deve ser possível ver a OCI8 na página do phpInfo:

[image]

Uma outra dica é verificar quais erros existem no seu php. Para fazer isso abra o prompt de comando e navegue até a pasta do php do xampp. no meu caso era "C:\xampp\php". Digite o comando 'php' e veja se há algum problema com as dlls habilitadas. Caso exista, o problema será mostrado. Se quiser fazer isso como teste na sua versão atual, veja se aparece alguma mensagem como "arquivo não encontrado" ou "arquivo não é win 32". Se aparecer, muito provavelmente essa solução, de passagem para versão 32 bits, irá resolver seu problema!