# Erro ao conectar o Codeigniter com Oracle

Tags: php, codeigniter, oracle, codeigniter-3

Estou tentando conectar o codeigniter com oracle e está dando esse erro:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function oci_connect() in C:\Apache24\htdocs\system\database\drivers\oci8\oci8_driver.php on line 238
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Error

Message: Call to undefined function oci_connect()

Filename: oci8/oci8_driver.php

Line Number: 238

Backtrace:
```

Estou usando o php  5.6.35 e apache 2.4. Já peguei o `instant_client_12` e joguei na minha pasta php e nada. Dei um `print_r(get_loaded_extensions());` ele mostra que carregou o `pdo_oci` mas o `oci8 não.`

```
Meu php.ini
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lhNx7.jpg

Algué já teve o mesmo problema e poderia me ajudar?

Obs: o php junto com o apache estão e uma máquina virtual da azure no windows server.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Fatal error: Call to undefined function oci\_connect()](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/275900/fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function-oci-connect)

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss Já segui a solução mas ela não funcionou para mim.

Comment: Já tive esse problema e o que eu fiz foi baixar novamente a dll  do oci8 correspondente a versão do PHP e jogar na pasta da instalação do PHP. [Link para download](https://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/oci8/2.0.8/)

Comment: @Piupz já havia feito isso, fiz  de novo e o erro persiste.

Comment: @William O que pode tentar tb é pegar a pasta `instant_client_12`, jogar na raiz do `disco C`  e alterar o PATH do windows apontando para `C:\instant_client_12\;`, feito isso, só reiniciar o apache para testar.

Comment: @Piupz o **instant_client_12** já está na pasta raiz, não sei se interfere mais a minha maquina não tem o PATH

Comment: Precisa configurar o path e tudo mais para funcionar, só ter a lib ali não funciona

Comment: Detalhe, você sempre precisar instalar a versão de *32 bits*, mesmo se o seu sistema operacional é 64 bits.